# MEAN.JS view does not show if link open in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, angular, meanjs

**Framework:** MEAN.JS v.0.4.2

I created new "orders" module using YO generator. Both `orders.list` and `orders.view` works fine. I **can** browse `orders.list` state directly using url `DOMAIN/orders` but I **can not** browse `orders.view` state directly using url for example `DOMAIN/orders/id123`. There is no error but the page is empty. Here is my route config file:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('orders')
    .config(routeConfig);

  routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('orders', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/orders',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
      })
      .state('orders.list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'modules/orders/client/views/list-orders.client.view.html',
        controller: 'OrdersListController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          orderResolve: getOrders
        },
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Orders List'
        }
      })
      .state('orders.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'modules/orders/client/views/form-order.client.view.html',
        controller: 'OrdersController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          orderResolve: newOrder
        },
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Orders Create'
        }
      })
      .state('orders.edit', {
        url: '/:orderId/edit',
        templateUrl: 'modules/orders/client/views/form-order.client.view.html',
        controller: 'OrdersController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          orderResolve: getOrder
        },
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Edit Order {{ orderResolve.name }}'
        }
      })
      .state('orders.view', {
        url: '/:orderId',
        templateUrl: 'modules/orders/client/views/view-order.client.view.html',
        controller: 'OrdersController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          orderResolve: getOrder
        },
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Order Details {{ orderResolve.name }}'
        }
      });
  }

  getOrder.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'OrdersService'];
  function getOrder($stateParams, OrdersService) {
    return OrdersService.get({orderId: $stateParams.orderId}).$promise;
  }

  newOrder.$inject = ['OrdersService'];
  function newOrder(OrdersService) {
    return new OrdersService();
  }
}());
```

Comment: Can you please create a Plunker? I will be easy to debug for everyone.

Comment: What's the output in the console when you visit DOMAIN/orders/id123 ? Maybe it can be that your user doesn't have enough permissions. Check `/modules/orders/server/policies/orders.server.policy.js` file.

Comment: I am new in MEANJS so didn't know about error log in console. Thanks for your suggestions. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the error in error log. I found view file is missing error. Put a slash at beginning of template url can solve this problem. For example:

templateUrl: '/modules/orders/client/views/...',